# ASP.Net, MVC, MEF and loading approved plugins (ie, plugins with known signer)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, plugins, mef, digital-signature

I'm working on an ASP.Net MVC/MEF based project.

Is it possible to build the catalog such that the DLLs added to the application are approved using a known signer? We don't want to load any old plugin that conforms - just those that have been approved (approving a plugin means its signed with a known key).

Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform filtering like this before you initialise the MEF catalog. I.e., if you're using `AssemblyCatalog`:

```
var assemblies = // all assemblies
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog(
    assemblies
        .Where(a => IsAcceptable(a))
        .Select(a => new AssemblyCatalog(a))
);
```

You need to supply the `IsAcceptable` method to perform assembly filtering as appropriate:

```
bool IsAcceptable(Assembly a) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var c = X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile(assemblyFile);
if (c.Issuer = "Joe") ...
```

just an idea, didnt tried :) let us know if it works..